# Android calling Dialog.show() directly after dismissing another dialog freezes app

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm trying to display a dialog directly after dismissing another one.

```
@Override
public void onLoginFailure(Exception e, boolean ttl) {
    if(DialogUtils.isDialogShowing()){
        //dismisses progress dialog
        DialogUtils.DIALOG.dismiss();
    }
    DialogUtils.showExceptionDialog(this, "TTL Expired.");
}
```

DialogUtils.java:

```
public volatile static Dialog DIALOG;

public static boolean isDialogShowing() {
    return (DIALOG!=null && DIALOG.isShowing());
}

public static Dialog showExceptionDialog(final Context ctx, final String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.exception_title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    if(isDialogShowing()) {
        DIALOG.dismiss();
    }
    DIALOG = builder.create();
    DIALOG.show();
    return DIALOG;
}

public static Dialog showLoggingInProgressDialog(final Context ctx, final boolean cancellable) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setCancelable(cancellable);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_login_title);
    //ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(ctx);
    //pb.setIndeterminate(true);
    //builder.setView(pb);
    if(isDialogShowing()) {
        DIALOG.dismiss();
    }
    DIALOG = builder.create();
    DIALOG.show();
    return DIALOG;
}
```

In this code, when onLoginFailure is invoked, a "Logging in..." progress dialog is being displayed.  I try to dismiss that dialog to display an error dialog, but calling .show() on the new dialog freezes the app.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE(12/16/13 8:53):
changing the action to take on failure doesn't freeze the app, but the Toast text is never displayed...?

```
@Override
public void onLoginFailure(Exception e, boolean ttl) {
    if(DialogUtils.isDialogShowing()){
        DialogUtils.DIALOG.dismiss();
    }
    if(ttl)
        //DialogUtils.showExceptionDialog(this, "TTL Expired.");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed:\nTTL Expired...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    else if(e!=null)
        //DialogUtils.showExceptionDialog(this, e);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed:\n" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat here, there should be some information that might help...

Comment: There's nothing interesting in logcat around the time the freezing begins.  After it's frozen, I get some ANR lines in logcat whenever i touch the UI, and some input event dispatch timeouts, but nothing else.

Comment: can you post useful part of the code? I think some where you are running infinite loop or burdening the UI thread...

Comment: i took the loop out of the code... changes visible in the original question.  problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(isDialogShowing()) {
    //
}
```

You're running an infinite loop?

Comment: it's not an infinite loop.  it's waiting for the dialog to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
while(isDialogShowing()) {
    //
}
DIALOG = builder.show();
```

with

```
if(isDialogShowing) {
    DIALOG.dismiss();
}
DIALOG = builder.create();
DIALOG.show();
```

in both show....Dialog(....) methods...